# How to handle space in a line in a file using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My file tool.txt which contains

```
DC OPTIMIZER,b_csw_load_14,s_get_bn_master_14,m_get_bn_master,
DC OPTIMIZER,b_csw_load_14,s_get_cu_qp_zones_14,m_get_qp_zones,
DI_ODS,wf_CSW82_ACTIVITY_DATA_to_ODS,s_m_CSW_BN_MASTER_to_ODS,m_CSW_BN_MASTER_to_ODS,
DI_ODS,wf_CSW82_ACTIVITY_DATA_to_ODS,s_m_CSW_IN_LOCATIONS_to_ODS,m_CSW_IN_LOCATIONS_to_ODS,
```

in my script

```
for i in `tail -n +2 /dssdev/appl/dss/sql/arun/tool.txt`
do
FOLDER=`echo $i|cut -d',' -f1`
WORKFLOW_NAME=`echo $i|cut -d',' -f2`
SESSION_NAME=`echo $i|cut -d',' -f3`
MAPPING_NAME=`echo $i|cut -d',' -f4`
MAPPLET_NAME=`echo $i|cut -d',' -f5`
echo $FOLDER'|'$WORKFLOW_NAME'|'$SESSION_NAME'|'$MAPPING_NAME'|'$MAPPLET_NAME>>tool1.csv
done
```

my output file contains

```
DC|DC|DC|DC|DC
OPTIMIZER|b_csw_load_14|s_get_bn_master_14|m_get_bn_master|
DC|DC|DC|DC|DC
OPTIMIZER|b_csw_load_14|s_get_cu_qp_zones_14|m_get_qp_zones|
DI_ODS|wf_CSW82_ACTIVITY_DATA_to_ODS|s_m_CSW_BN_MASTER_to_ODS|m_CSW_BN_MASTER_to_ODS|
DI_ODS|wf_CSW82_ACTIVITY_DATA_to_ODS|s_m_CSW_IN_LOCATIONS_to_ODS|m_CSW_IN_LOCATIONS_to_ODS|
```

But My requirement is

```
DC OPTIMIZER|b_csw_load_14|s_get_bn_master_14|m_get_bn_master|
DC OPTIMIZER|b_csw_load_14|s_get_cu_qp_zones_14|m_get_qp_zones|
DI_ODS|wf_CSW82_ACTIVITY_DATA_to_ODS|s_m_CSW_BN_MASTER_to_ODS|m_CSW_BN_MASTER_to_ODS|
DI_ODS|wf_CSW82_ACTIVITY_DATA_to_ODS|s_m_CSW_IN_LOCATIONS_to_ODS|m_CSW_IN_LOCATIONS_to_ODS|
```

Space between `DC` and `OPTIMIZER` is the problem.

Comment: `tr ',' '|' < input.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the entire code in a single while as

```
while IFS="," read -r FOLDER WORKFLOW_NAME SESSION_NAME MAPPING_NAME MAPPLET_NAME
do 
echo "$FOLDER|$WORKFLOW_NAME|$SESSION_NAME|$MAPPING_NAME|$MAPPLET_NAME" 
done < input >> tool1.csv
```

Gives output as

```
DC OPTIMIZER|b_csw_load_14|s_get_bn_master_14|m_get_bn_master|
DC OPTIMIZER|b_csw_load_14|s_get_cu_qp_zones_14|m_get_qp_zones|
DI_ODS|wf_CSW82_ACTIVITY_DATA_to_ODS|s_m_CSW_BN_MASTER_to_ODS|m_CSW_BN_MASTER_to_ODS|
DI_ODS|wf_CSW82_ACTIVITY_DATA_to_ODS|s_m_CSW_IN_LOCATIONS_to_ODS|m_CSW_IN_LOCATIONS_to_ODS|
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I intentionally missed them to give output in standard input. Will anyway edit the answer. Thank you :)

Comment: I meant the trailing `|` symbol `:)`. Would be better to put the redirection after the loop: `done < input > tool1.csv` or `done < input >> tool1.csv` so as to not have an unnecessary large number of opening/closing.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I just noticed that :P But actually the if we add a trailing `|` , then the output will end with two `||` because the the input contain only 4 fields where as OP tries to read 5 fields :/

Comment: Also, note that OP parses `tail -n +2` to skip the first line. Could use a grouping and an extra dummy read: `{ read -r; while IFS=, read -r ...; done } < input >> tool1.csv`. Also it's better to use `printf '%s\n' "$stuff"` instead of `echo "$stuff"`, since `echo` has a few caveats… sorry to bother you `:D`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Never mind to bother again. Its great to learn new things from new people. Really appreciate any inputs. Thank you :)

Comment: It works fine.. But what is the problem with for loop i used initially? why it is not working?

Comment: @user2391806 It faild because the `$i` does not contain the entire line as you expcetd it to be as the there are spaces in the output of tail where by the `$i` will read upto a space or newline. Try `echo $i` to see the contents of the variable

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to read the lines with "read"?

```
while read line           
do           
    command           
done < file
```

Then you have a seeperate line and you can split it with awk or cut ...